# How to associate an Azure app service with an application insights resource (new or existing) using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I looked at the documentation of both [azurerm_app_service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/app_service.html) and [azurerm_application_insights](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/application_insights.html) and I just do not see a way to tie them.

Yet on the App Service page in the portal there is a link to Application Insights, currently grayed out:
[image]

So, how do I enable it with terraform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that enabling application insights using Terraform is not working yet currently. There is a [Feature Request: Attach azurerm_application_insights to a azurerm_app_service](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1303) in Github.

It might be possible to set a `tag` on the `azurerm_application_insights` resource,

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "test" {
  tags {
    "hidden-link:/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<rg name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<site name>": "Resource"
  }
}
```

Usually, if you need to enable application insights component in your app service, you need to add `APPINSIGHTS_*` environment variables to the `app_settings` of your web app.

For example,

```
 app_settings {
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = "${azurerm_application_insights.test.instrumentation_key}"
  }
```

See [argument reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html#argument-reference) even it's about Azure function.

[image]
ref: 
https://www.olivercoding.com/2018-06-24-terraform/

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2457

Comment: We use Asp.Net Core and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core the key should be `ApplicationInsights__InstrumentationKey`.

Answer (score 10):

You need numerous app settings to get this to work properly as intended.  The ones I had to add to get it all working were:

- "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"
- "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION"
- "APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION"
- "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"
- "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"
- "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION"
- "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION"
- "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION"
- "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions"
- "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode"

Comment: This worked for App Service (not just function). Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me in App Service as well. Look up each individual setting to see what the possible values are. An alternative is to first configure Application Insights manually in the portal -> View your Configuration tab to see all the app settings which Azure automatically set -> copy these into terraform. When I did this, there were some additional settings I included.

Answer (score 2):

There is one key variable allow for particular language and OS version:

```
  {
"name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
"value": "~3",
"slotSetting": false  }
```

1. Value=~2 is for windows APP
2. Value=~3 is for Linux APP

Reference Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps-nodejs?tabs=windows