# How do I configure app insights instrumentation for app service via terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

How do I configure App Insights instrumentation for an app service via Terraform?  Is it all via `app_settings`, or is there a resource I am missing?

I create app insights resource:

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "app1" {
  for_each = local.all_envs
  application_type    = "web"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-webapps.location
  name                = "appi-app1-${each.value}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-webapps.name
  retention_in_days   = 30
  sampling_percentage = 0
  workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log-analytics-workspace[each.value].id
}
```

I tie it to my app service:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "app1" {
  name                = "app1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-webapps.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-webapps.name
  ...

  app_settings = {
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_ROLE_NAME   = "role1"
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = azurerm_application_insights.app1["dev"].instrumentation_key
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = azurerm_application_insights.app1["dev"].connection_string
  }
  ...
```

}

But it says application insights is not fully enabled:

[image]

Is instrumentation controlled by these config keys, which I have to manually set?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to check with appsettings for instrumentation key and connection string in my case and it was not enabled in portal.

```
app_settings = {

    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"                  = azurerm_application_insights.<app>.instrumentation_key
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"           = azurerm_application_insights.<app>.connection_string
}
```

[image]

Also include ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION in the app settings .

```
app_settings = {

    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"                  = azurerm_application_insights.<app>.instrumentation_key
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"           = azurerm_application_insights.<app>.connection_string
     "APPINSIGHTS_PORTALINFO"                         =         "ASP.NET"
      "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION"           =        "1.0.0"
    "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"      =          "~2"
}
```

For working properly, your app may require additional settings from below: check what works for your app.

> - "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"
> - "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION"
> - "APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION"
> - "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"
> - "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"
> - "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION"
> - "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION"
> - "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION"
> - "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions"
> - "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode"

And try to set a tag on the azurerm_application_insights  as said by  nancy in [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175600/how-to-associate-an-azure-app-service-with-an-application-insights-resource-new/60179336#60179336)

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "webapp-ka-repo" {
...
  tags {
    "hidden-link:/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<rg name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<site name>": "Resource"
  }
}
```

or

```
tags = {
    "hidden-link:/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<sitename>” = "Resource"
  }
```

and check if it is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Hi, ignore those hidden-link tags they're exposed due to a bug / incompatibility issue. Add a lifecycle to ignore these, see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16569

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem myself, a linux app plan with two apps

1. linux_web_app
2. linux_function_app

the function_app was really straight forward,  it could be assosiated and enabled via the ***site_config*** block of the function app resource

```
 site_config {
    always_on                              = false
    application_insights_connection_string = azurerm_application_insights.<your_app_insights_resource_name>.connection_string
    application_insights_key               = azurerm_application_insights.<your_app_insights_resource_name>.instrumentation_key
  }
```

However the web_app was a bit trickier:
configured through the ***app_settings*** argument, started with the same two

```
app_settings = {
  APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = "${azurerm_application_insights.<your_app_insights_resource_name>.instrumentation_key}"
  APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = "${azurerm_application_insights.<your_app_insights_resource_name>.connection_string}"
}
```

this seemed to link or associate the web_app with app_insights, but frustratingly, NOT enable it!

after spending way to long trying other suggestions found on the internet, and not getting anywher,  i asked our friendly neighbourhood AI if it had any suggestions, and it did...

adding the following config to the  ***app_settings***

```
APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION = "1.0.0"
APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION = "1.0.0"
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~2"
DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~3"
InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~2"
SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION = "1.0.15"
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions = "disabled"
XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode = "recommended"
```

seemed to do the trick in my case, hope this helps